# Is the literal 0xffffffff int or unsigned in C++

Tags: c++, integer, literals

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal), integer literals without type suffix are always `int`s. However, both gcc and clang interpret `0xffffffff` (or any literal which explicitly sets the sign bit other than using the `-`) as unsigned. Which is correct? (according to [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) the compilers are)

Comment: I don't know, but I'm interested to know why it matters.

Comment: @roger_rowland it doesn't, presumably, but clang warns me about a conversion from unsigned to signed, which is annoying and which I didn't understand

Comment: I guess the point is 0xffffffff = 4294967295 are positive numbers and do not fit in an int.

Comment: `std::is_signed<decltype(0xffffffff)>::value` will tell you.

Comment: @Pubby I know what the compiler thinks. I wanted to know what the rules say.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per Paragraph 2.14.2/2 of the C++11 Standard,

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be
>   represented.

Table 6 reports that for hexadecimal constants, the type should be:

- `int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `unsigned int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `long int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `unsigned long int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `long long int`; or
- `unsigned long long int`.

Assuming your implementation has 32-bit `int`, since `0xffffffff` does not fit in an `int`, its type should be `unsigned int`. For an implementation with a 64-bit `int`, the type would be `int`.

Notice, that if you had written the same literal as a *decimal* constant instead, the type could have only been:

- `int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `long int`; or (if it doesn't fit)
- `long long int`.

Comment: Interesting. Would you please link the quote to its online web-page, if it's possible?

Comment: @MM.: This is the C++11 Standard (I am using Draft 3485, which is slightly more recent than the official Standard). The Draft can be downloaded for free from [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf). The official Standard is paid.