# C++ / OpenGL: Texture to pixmap example - narrowing conversion error

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, type-conversion, narrowing

I am trying to run this [texture to pixmap example](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Programming_OpenGL_in_Linux:_Using_texture_from_pixmap_extension) from OpenGL and get the following error

```
tex_to_pix.cpp:40:1: error: narrowing conversion of ‘4294967295u’ from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

The error refers to the following code block of the example:

```
const int pixmap_config[] = {
    GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA_EXT, True,
    GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PIXMAP_BIT,
    GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_TARGETS_EXT, GLX_TEXTURE_2D_BIT_EXT,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, False,
    GLX_Y_INVERTED_EXT, GLX_DONT_CARE,
    None
};
```

What is the reason for this error?

Is it a compiler or c++11 problem?

Is there a way i can either make my compiler ignore -Wnarrowing or make a safe conversion?

Comment: Instead of `const int pixmap_config[] ...`, try `const unsigned int pixmap_config[] ...`

Comment: @Amadeus: The function `glXChooseFBConfig(Display *dpy, int screen, const int *pixmap_config, int *nitems)` needs pixmap_config to be a `const int*`. `glXChooseFBConfig` gets used in line 158.

Comment: Seems to me that it is a problem with the API. You could try to compile in c++03 or try to disable this warning (search in google for "disable narrowing warning g++" or whatever compiler you are using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `GLX_DONT_CARE` which is defined as:

```
#define GLX_DONT_CARE                     0xFFFFFFFF
```

Because this value does not fit into a 32-bit `int`, its type is `unsigned int` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15744362/860585)). The rules for narrowing conversion were indeed changed in c++11.

Trying to implicitly convert this `unsigned int` into an `int` causes the narrowing conversion warning. As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434140/narrowing-conversions-in-c0x-is-it-just-me-or-does-this-sound-like-a-breakin), the narrowing problem can be fixed by using **static_cast(GLX_DONT_CARE & 0xFFFFFFFF)** instead of **GLX_DONT_CARE**

```
const int pixmap_config[] = {
    GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_RGBA_EXT, True,
    GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PIXMAP_BIT,
    GLX_BIND_TO_TEXTURE_TARGETS_EXT, GLX_TEXTURE_2D_BIT_EXT,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, False,
    GLX_Y_INVERTED_EXT, static_cast<int>(GLX_DONT_CARE & 0xFFFFFFFF),
    None
};
```

Alternatively, disable narrowing conversion errors in your compiler (unspecified).

Comment: @ephtron Why do we need that `&`? `GLX_DONT_CARE` is already `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: My mistake. Its not needed. `static_cast<int>` is enough.