# sign of 0xFFFFFFFF and 0xFFFFFFFE for 32bit int

Tags: c++

According to most voted ansewer here: [Is the literal 0xffffffff int or unsigned in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744310/is-the-literal-0xffffffff-int-or-unsigned-in-c). There says "Assuming your implementation has 32-bit int, since 0xffffffff does not fit in an int, its type should be unsigned int." unfortunately, can't comment there due to new here.

Question 1: but why does not 0xffffffff fit in an int? Because its value is 4294967295? If yes, then we are interpreting it as `unsigned` already. why don't we interpret it as `signed -1`?

I also run the following code, (compiler is clang, 32bit int):

```
cout << std::is_signed<decltype(0xffffffff)>::value << " " << 0xffffffff << endl;
cout << std::is_signed<decltype(0xffffffe)>::value << " " << 0xfffffffe << endl;

bool same = std::is_same_v<decltype(0xffffffff), decltype(0xfffffffe)>;
std::cout << "0xFFFFFFFF and 0xFFFFFFFE are the same type? " << std::boolalpha << same << '\n';

decltype(0xffffffff) a = -1;
decltype(0xfffffffe) b = -1;
cout << a << " " << b << endl;
```

The output is:

```
0 4294967295
1 4294967294
0xFFFFFFFF and 0xFFFFFFFE are the same type? true
4294967295 4294967295
```

Question 2: why do 0xffffffff and 0xfffffffe have different signs but are the same type?

Question 3: if the sign of 0xfffffffe is 1, then why isn't itself a negative number?

Question 4: if the sign of 0xfffffffe is 1, then why isn't `b` -1?

Comment: C++ does not interpret negative numbers.  It only interprets positive numbers, and then afterward is applies the *unary negation* to the positive number.  So `-1` is interpreted as *unary negation* applied to a *positive* `1`.  (This does have a few unfortunate edge-case consequences that need to be worked around, for example, look at how INT_MIN is implemented in your compiler's header file.)

Comment: Also `0xffffffe` is not `0xfffffffe`.

Comment: Q2: They are not of different signs, they are of different types. `int` vs `unsigned int`

Comment: On the second line, `std::is_signed<decltype(0xffffffe)>`, you left out one digit.  `0xffffffe` (7 digits) is indeed a positive `signed int`.   Maybe you should fix this and then see if you still have a question.

Comment: You may also want to read about [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and how they get their associated "best fit" type.  (It's a bit convoluted.)